# Mail sent response solution

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a form using codeignitor where in once I fill in the basic details in the form, a mail is sent to the customer where a link is being send to them to proceed further. The mail is working all good. But once the mail is being sent I receive the following page which I don't want to be seen [After mail has been sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMvoG.png)

I have added made the following changes in controllers section but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
function processVendor()
{
    $data = $this->array_from_post(array('vendor_name','vendor_phone','vendor_email','vendor_address','vendor_zipcode','vendor_city','vendor_state','vendor_country'));

    if($data)
    {
        $data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $res = $this->db->insert('vendors',$data);

        $response = vendorContinuationLink($data);
        var_dump($response);

        if($response)
        {
            redirect('joinus/complete');
        }
    }       
}
```

The complete.php page doesn't show up. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: var_dump($response); is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `var_dump()` in your code. That is printing the values.

```
function processVendor()
{
$data = $this->array_from_post(array('vendor_name','vendor_phone','vendor_email','vendor_address','vendor_zipcode','vendor_city','vendor_state','vendor_country'));
if($data)
{
    $data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $res = $this->db->insert('vendors',$data);
    $response = vendorContinuationLink($data);
    //var_dump($response);//comment or remove this.
    if($response)
    {
        redirect('joinus/complete');
    }
}       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delete `var_dump($response);`